# Is there a way I can find every RigidBody in a specific layer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game where I need gravity like physics. Im trying to find the center of mass of every RigidBody (exept the one running the script) in a specific layer.
I have this:

```
float AvrgMass;
float count = 0f;
Vector3 AvrgPoisition = Vector3.zero;

void Update(){

    foreach (Rigidbody2D Body in "THELAYER")
    {
        AvrgPoisition += Body.transform.position;
        AvrgMass += Body.mass;
        count++;
    }

    AvrgPoissition -= ThisBody.transform.position;
    AvrgMass -= ThisBody.mass;
    AvrgPoisition /= count;
    AvrgMass /= count;
}
```

Am I going in the right direction? What should "THELAYER" be?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting all the rigid bodies and inside your foreach, test wether they match the layer you need.

It would be something like this:

```cs
RigidBody2D[] allRigidBodies = (RigidBody2D[]) GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(RigidBody2D));

foreach(Rigidbody2D body in allRigidBodies)
 {
     if(body.gameObject.layer==THE_LAYER)
         // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: The "body.layer" isnt working for me. It says "no additional methods for layer where found".

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to access the game object related to the body `body.gameObject.layer`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in function for that.
What I think you can do is to get all GameObjects in the scene, then loop through to get what you want. For example:

```
GameObjects[] gameObjects=GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[];
```

You can ignore the GameObject with the script.

```
foreach(GameObject go in gameObjects){
if(go.name!="GameManager" && go.layer=="layerName"){
RigidBody2D rb2d=go.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
//Do some stuff
AvrgPoisition += rb2d.transform.position;
 AvrgMass += rb2d.mass;
 count++;
//Etc
}
}
```

Be careful though, you don't want to run this code in the `Update()` function.

Comment: Do I need any additional namespace?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you ask?

Comment: Almost everything is underlined and it says "is the using or build reference missing?"

Comment: But I aprecciate it anyways

Comment: I think I will be able to run it if I make the "go.layer" work. Specificaly, the "layer" doesnt work.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? I think something might have changed in 2019.1 or so.

Comment: Unity 2018.2.14.f1

Comment: I will come back to this in the morning, thanks for the help

Comment: Alright. From the 2019 documentation,` layer` returns an `int`. That might be the issue. Try `go.layer==5;` or whatever the layer number is.

Comment: I updated Unity, but now Unity itself is complaining: "C:/Users/milan/Documents/MyGame/MyGame/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/FastAction.cs(24,45): error CS1644: Feature `out variable declaration' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification" so I updated Visual studio but that didnt solve anything either. Atleast I changed the Visual studio Language to English so I will be able to post screenshots.